# The Unity "Application.Quit()" function is quiting Android Studio Emulator

Tags: android-studio, unity-game-engine

While testing my game on the Android Virtual Device (emulator) in Android Studio, I noticed that when I press the close button, the game exits as expected, but the Android Studio emulator itself also closes after a delay of 2-3 seconds. I've confirmed that this behavior only occurs when the close button is pressed.
Note: The Device Manager Status Show that the Device/Emulator is still running.
[Img Refrence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c92zj.png)

In my Unity game, I have a 'Close' button that invokes the 'QuitTheGame' function, which uses 'Application.Quit()' to exit the game.

```
 public void QuitTheGame()
    {
            Application.Quit();
    }
```

How to prevent this?

Comment: is there no conditional compile option you can use to say if in android studio?

Comment: @BugFinder 
I appreciate the suggestion, but I'm not entirely sure what code to include for handling the close action on Android. Could you provide more guidance or an example of what might be suitable in this case?"

Comment: the one line application.quit.. otherwise you'd get compile errors method not found